# Localized URL issue on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization

I have some issue about the routes.

I have localized urls in my app for the same pages like forexample,

"domain.com/en/giveaway"

"domain.com/es/sorteo"

My lang.routes files is like

lang.en.routes

```
return [
         'giveaway' => 'giveaway'
       ]
```

lang.es.routes

```
return [
         'giveaway' => 'sorteo'
       ]
```

Also My route is like

```
$l = app()->getLocale();

$lang = [
           'giveaway' => __('routes.giveaway', [], $l),
        ];

Route::group(['prefix' => $locale], function () use ($lang) {

     Route::get($lang['giveaway'], "Auth\GiveawayController@index")->name('giveaway');

});
```

this will work properly on my blade. When I call

```
route('giveaway')


//if app Locale is en returns domain.com/en/giveaway
//if app Locale is es returns domain.com/es/sorteo
```

No problem thorugh here.

But my problem is;

How i can show the google alternate hreflang?

How can access to domain.com/es/sorteo url when app locale is en?

Is there any idea?

I want to do this in blade like

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en"
                  href="{{route(Request::route()->getName())->getLocalized('en')}}"/>  

  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es"
                  href="{{route(Request::route()->getName())->getLocalized('es')}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the previous comment, I misunderstood the question. Try something like this:

Create a helper file and autoload in composer.json, which contains something like this:

```
if(!function_exists("localroute")){
   function localroute($name, $locale){
       $old_locale = app()->getLocale();
       app()->setlocale($locale);
       $route = route($name);
       app()->setlocale($old_locale);
       return $route;
   }
}
```

then simply call `localroute("giveaway")`.

Comment: Thanks taha, i will try and brief you, actually i’ve tried this way in blade, but didn’t work.

Comment: Taha it is not work. because i am changing the locale in routes.web file depending to first url segment.

But if i set the locale in any middleware, should work your answer but if i set locale in middleware, it doesn't effect to routes.web file, always return default locale. Is there a way run a middleware before process routes?

Comment: But you are using this function in your view right? When everything is ready, all routes are set, etc. It should work in views.